# Passing values from one JSP application to another JSP application through header

Tags: header, request, response

I want to pass the values through header from one JSP application to another JSP application which is running at different domain.

We have the URL of the application of different domain. That application is taking value from header.

How to pass the values from header to that application & we are invoking that URL by submitting form.

---

```
document.form.method = "post";
document.form.action = "URL";
document.form.submit();
```